# Disassembling an .EXE file using OllyDBG gives strange results

Tags: disassembly, ollydbg

I'm trying to disassemble a software in ollydbg and I found something strange. It's something like the following:

```
ASCII"C:\FolderName\SubFolder\exec.h"
ASCII"C:\FolderName\SubFolder\Include\variable.cpp"
```

I don't have a folder named `FolderName` in `C` but the software is running fine. What could this be?

Comment: When you as question and what to show something the looks like code or listing it's the best to select the text and click on "code sample", that's the toolbar button with the `{ }` or you press `Ctrl+K`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be the paths associated with debugging symbols.

My only experience is on linux, where the path to the source on the compilation computer is included in the executable (when compiled with debugging symbols)

Comment: i've been searching at google and it say something about virtual machine?

Comment: What have you been searching?

Comment: i got the information from the developer, this software i decompile are fully compiled into a virtual machine. and from wikipedia debug symbol embed the library to the software

Comment: It´s probably compiled *on* a VM. And no, debug symbol are not the same as the linker.

Comment: what keyword that can i use for search about 'compiled on a vm', i google it and i just got something like virualbox or vmware. so linker is just give the `path-to-the-lib` than debug symbol is `embed-the-lib` ?

Comment: @kanamichan I don´t understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The executable include paths in the debug information. The strings you find are not related to your PC but the the environment at the PC where the EXE has been built.

*Edit*:

The format

```
ASCII"C\FolderName\SubFolder\exec.h"
```

in your disassembler output probably indicates that the string following `ASCII` is an ASCII string.

Comment: so this ascii mean nothing?

Comment: It probably means that it´s ASCII ...?